# Get a list of all markers in the searched area in Google Maps - Markerclusterer v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I need to get a list of markers in the zoomed area in Google Maps.

I've checked out this other question: [Get a list of markers in bounds of google map using markerclusterer v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487578/get-a-list-of-markers-in-bounds-of-google-map-using-markerclusterer-v3)

Which is close to what i want, but not exactly the same.

This is my JavaScript to generate the map

```
$('#autocomplete').click(function() {
  $(this).val('');
   $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
});
var map, places, infoWindow;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;
var countryRestrict = {
    'country': 'dk'
};

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: {
            lat: 56.220512,
            lng: 11.245051
        },
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (
            document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
            componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
        });
    places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

    setMarkers(map);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {} else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(10);
        }
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

    });
}
var beaches = [
    <?php while ( have_rows('tilfoj_vaerksted_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>

    ['test', <?php the_sub_field('latitude_tilfoj_vaerksted_repeater'); ?>, <?php the_sub_field('longitude_tilfoj_vaerksted_repeater'); ?>, 4],
    <?php endwhile; ?>

];

function setMarkers(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
        var beach = beaches[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: beach[1],
                lng: beach[2]
            },
            map: map,
            icon: "/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/map-icon.png",
        });
    }
}

function onPlaceChanged() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.geometry) {
        map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(10);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Søg';
    }


}
```

What i exactly need is to get all markers in the searched area within the Google Maps and then hide/show the div elements below the Google Map. You can see the current example in the link below. I think i can use Markercluster but i'm not quite sure how to do this.

This is a link to the production site:

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906427/how-to-get-all-visible-markers-on-current-zoom-level

Comment: @AswinKumar Thank you for the comment. I have tried this code, but i can't seem to get it to work or implement it into my code..

Comment: @AswinKumar I found an soloution. Thx for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works perfectly.

```
function showVisibleMarkers() {
var bounds = map.getBounds(),
    count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var marker = markers[i], // array indexes start at zero, but not our class names :)
        infoPanel = jQuery('.workplace' + (i)); // array indexes start at zero, but not our class names :)
    if (bounds.contains(marker.getPosition()) === true) {
        infoPanel.show();
        count++;
    } else {
        infoPanel.hide();
    }
}

}

function setMarkers(map) {

for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i],
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            title: beach[0],
            icon: "/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/map-icon.png",
        });
    marker.setMap(map);

    markers.push(marker);
}

}
```