# How can I properly change a marker position in Google Maps every x number of seconds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, setinterval

So let me first show my code:

```
var marker;
var map;
initMap();

function initMap() {
    axios.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json').then(function (response) {
        var coords = response.data.iss_position
        var position = {
            lat: parseFloat(coords.latitude),
            lng: parseFloat(coords.longitude)
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: position
        });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
        });
    })
}

function loadPosition() {
    axios.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json').then(function (response) {
        var coords = response.data.iss_position
        var newPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords.latitude), parseFloat(coords.longitude));
        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
        map.setCenter(newPosition);
        console.log(coords)
    })
}

setInterval(function () {
    loadPosition()
}, 2000)
```

As you can see, I am using the http://open-notify.org/ API (Open APIs From Space) to make my marker real-time. The marker serves as the ISS(International Space Station) and how I update the marker is to do a setInterval every 2 seconds.

I've heard that it is a bad practice but is there any other way that will make the performance better? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: basically u r reloading the position as of now so as of now did u experianced any slow down in application?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice actually everything is good, but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do this.

Comment: It looks good to me but do you always need to center the map?

You can check if the marker is in the map bounds and if not, you can call the setCenter method.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648545/how-can-i-check-the-marker-is-or-isnt-in-the-bounds-using-google-maps-v3

Comment: @FewFlyBy actually it is proper approach , i cannot say best but i think map have limitations in rerendering i had faced recently in javascript , but if ur map is not so customized then u refresh it via `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

Comment: @AlperÖzhan nice link, I'll look into that

Comment: I don't think the code above is a bad practice at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `setInterval` in itself is not really a bad practice. It all depends on what you want to accomplish.

In this case it would probably be better to only start the next request when the current one has finished. Because it's an AJAX request and you never know when it might finish, if you just keep firing it blindly every 2 seconds you might get intermittent results.

```
var marker;
var map;

function initMap() {
    axios.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json').then(function (response) {
        var coords = response.data.iss_position
        var position = {
            lat: parseFloat(coords.latitude),
            lng: parseFloat(coords.longitude)
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: position
        });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
        });

        window.setTimeout(loadPosition, 2000);
    });
}

function loadPosition() {
    axios.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json').then(function (response) {
        var coords = response.data.iss_position
        var newPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords.latitude), parseFloat(coords.longitude));
        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
        map.setCenter(newPosition);
        console.log(coords);

        window.setTimeout(loadPosition, 2000);
    });
}

initMap();
```